# How to create a custom event in Policy Center

Tags: guidewire

I was asked to create a custom event in Policy Center.  A GuideWire employee said that I should see the GuideWire docs.  I searched the documents that I had and all I could find was how to add a new event for something in Billing Center.  It seemed to suggest that I should add the new event to the type list.  There doesn't seem to be a type list for the other types of events that I am monitoring, so that doesn't seem to be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be as simple as calling

```
.addEvent("CustomeEvent")
```

on any entity object.

What you probably should read is the `Messaging` section of the `Integration Guide` in the documentation. This new event - whatever you call it - has to be mentioned in Messaging part of the configuration on the particular destination and then appropriately filtered/handled in `Event Fired Rules`.

Comment: Thank you.  I actually came to the same conclusion by digging around in our customization code.